# How do you include a class from another branch in phpunit in CI Gitlab?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, phpunit, gitlab

I'm new to Gitlab, I need to write a small php project and test it with PHPUnit. I set everything up, the pipeline is running and a trivial `$this->assertContains('foo', 'foobar', '', true)` works. Now I'm trying to test a class that I have in the development branch. How can I include it in my phpunit test file? As a first step I'd just like to test the constructor of Hotel and this is the test I wrote

```
declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
require_once('Hotel.php');
final class TestHotel extends TestCase
{
    public function testBuildHotel(): void
    {
        $hotel = new Hotel('First hotel', '/image/path', 'Its the first hotel');
        $this->assertEquals($hotel->name, 'First hotel');
        $this->assertEquals($hotel->image, '/image/path');
        $this->assertEquals($hotel->description, 'Its the first hotel');
    }
}
```

I get the error that Hotel doesn't exist. The Hotel.php file sits in the root of the development branch (the test is in the master). How do I include it?

Thanks,

Ben

EDIT:
The Hotel.php is not in the test folder as I wrote above, it's one directory above (in the root), just on the dev branch. I tried 
`$root_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
require_once($root_folder.'/Hotel.php');`, It's not working either.

Comment: is the Hotel.php file exist on the same folder where the TestHotel.php file exist ?

Comment: Hi, yes, they're both in the root but on a different branch

Comment: why so complicated like that ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is one folder above, I'll modify the question. If you have a simpler idea I'd love to hear it, as far as I understand the tests should be in master branch and the rest in development branch

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI do you have a simpler idea?
Thanks